# Understanding Valgrind's output

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing a project for university. It's all done, passes all the tests, runs fine, but Valgrind tells me this:

```
==8059== Invalid read of size 8
==8059==    at 0x406E4E: RegPoly::getCurrentCoefficient() const (RegPoly.cpp:59)
==8059==    by 0x403368: MyPoly::operator+(MyPoly const&) const (MyPoly.cpp:281)
==8059==    by 0x403A6D: MyPoly::operator+=(MyPoly const&) (MyPoly.cpp:354)
==8059==    by 0x401E20: main (DemoPoly.cpp:50)
==8059==  Address 0x5953f50 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==8059==    at 0x4C27297: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8059==    by 0x4060CD: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==8059==    by 0x405934: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /a/fr-05/vol/home/stud/lablabla/CppLab/Ex3/DemoPoly)
==8059==    by 0x407355: double* std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >(unsigned long, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >) (stl_vector.h:1052)
==8059==    by 0x40700E: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (vector.tcc:167)
==8059==    by 0x406C5D: RegPoly::RegPoly(RegPoly const&) (RegPoly.cpp:19)
==8059==    by 0x4031DB: MyPoly::operator=(MyPoly const&) (MyPoly.cpp:249)
==8059==    by 0x403B58: MyPoly::operator*=(MyPoly const&) (MyPoly.cpp:364)
==8059==    by 0x401DB6: main (DemoPoly.cpp:44)
```

The lines:

44 - `p3 *= p2; // both are MyPoly objects`

50 - `p3 += p1;`

I kind of understand that it means that I'm trying to read from a memory that has been changed (?), but I couldn't understand why.
I could post the relevant code, only, I'm not sure which part, as it would make the question messy. I can paste relevant parts, just tell me what you need.

Here's the code:

```
MyPoly& MyPoly::operator *=(const MyPoly& rhs)
{
    *this = *this * rhs; // 364
    return *this;
}

// ===================

case PolyInterface::REG:
{
    RegPoly *tempReg = dynamic_cast<RegPoly*>(rhs.p_PolyBody); // rhs is an interface, hence the dynamic cast
    if (tempReg != NULL)
    {
        p_PolyBody = new RegPoly(*tempReg);  // 249. p_PolyBody is a pointer stored in MyPoly. points to RegPoly object
    }
    break;
}

// ===================

RegPoly::RegPoly(RegPoly const& other)
{
    gCurrentRank = 0;
    gData = other.gData; // 19. gData is a vector<double>
    _isZeroPoly = other._isZeroPoly;
}

// ===================

double RegPoly::getCurrentCoefficient() const
{
    return *gDataIterator; // 59. vector<double>::const_iterator
}

// ===================

newPolyValues.push_back(
                p_PolyBody->getCurrentCoefficient() + rhs.p_PolyBody->getCurrentCoefficient());
// 281.
```

I'm also getting this when `getCurrentCoefficient()` returns `gData[gCurrentRank]`, meaning that it's something with the location of gData itself, right?

RegPoly:

```
std::vector<double> gData;
std::vector<double>::iterator gDataIterator;
int gCurrentRank;
bool _isZeroPoly; // Inherited from the interface
```

Comment: How many member variables the RegPoly class has?

Comment: Added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: gDataIterator is a const_iterator or iterator? Unless you are extremely careful, I think you should get rid of the iterator member and use a double variable. Iterator points to an address. This address can point to anywhere without notice.

Comment: i tried both const and iterator.
I removed the iterator completely, no gDataIterator at all in RegPoly. I'm still getting the same leaks

Comment: This message is not a leak exactly. It is more like a memory violation that can possibly will result into a segmentation fault. Is it always the same report from valgrind?

Comment: Yes, always the same report on the same location in the program witht he same size

Comment: Is it possiblie that these 'leaks' origin from something in the std::vector object itself?

Comment: I doubt. You said the iterator was removed, why the report is still the same? Are you sure that is always generating a new report?

Comment: Yes. I re compiled, deleted all the objects filed and 'make' again. same report, same lines. no iterator in the code..

Comment: Well, I really don't know how can I help you. If you don't mind, make the source code available at github or any other site, or send it directly to me. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Trust Valgrind. It almost always shows existing problems.

Here is how you read the message:

`RegPoly::getCurrentCoefficient() const (RegPoly.cpp:59)` tried to read from a memory location it shouldn't have read, because it doesn't belong to your app (wasn't allocated, non-stack, etc...).

This invalid address was just beyond the space that was allocated with the *new* operator, used in your `RegPoly` copy constructor (and you can see the whole backtrace that created that call).

I don't see that your copy constructor copies `gDataIterator`.

Comment: is calling gDataIterator = other.gDataIterator; enough? cause i'm still getting the errors from valgrind will it make a deep copy of the iterator? also, I changed now the gCurrentRank

Comment: It is not enough. The problem is: the other iterator (probably) is pointing to another address that can change at any time (when an element is inserted, erased). You have to initialize with a valid address.

Comment: so doing gDataIterator = gData.begin(); after gData has been copied is needed? tried it, still the same. (btw, copying vector like this gData = other.gData is ok right? it copies the values into gData, right?)

Comment: Yes, because gDataIterator iterator can point to an address belonging to another container. About the copy, yes(cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator=). Why not save just the double value instead of iterator?

Comment: Tried, removed gDataIterator completely, still getting the same. I think it has something to do with gData, the vector, itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on *RegPoly.cpp:59*, not in *DemoPoly.cpp:50*.

It is stated that you had allocated 16 bytes, but it is trying to read 8 bytes beyond your allocation.

See this: *[4.2. Explanation of error messages from Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs)*

Probably you are trying to access an invalid iterator. A const iterator just means that you are not able use this iterator to modify a value inside a container.

A [brief explanation](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/018.htm) related to invalid iterators.

Comment: that's bit of a wild guess, the problem could also be where he allocates the space...

Comment: Hm, can you elaborate? To me it is clear that an invalid location on memory was read.  I did not understand what you are trying to imply as "wild guess".

Comment: I've added checks to getCurrentCoefficient() to make sure gDataIterator is less (checked also !=) thank gData.end(). still getting the same. The dereferencing *gDataIterator is the problem, any ideas why?